# jQuery: return all matched elements' position().left as an array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I want to get an array of all matched elements' `position().left`

but I am not familiar with `.map()`:

I know how to get it by using a `loop` though:

```
     var arr = new Array();

     var b = $(".matchME").length;
     var a = 0;

     for(i=0; i< b; i++){
        var c = $(".matchME:eq("+ a+ ")").position().left;
        arr.push(c);
        a++;
     }
```

But I get it wrong as I try using `.map()` :

```
var arr = $('.matchME').map(function(i,e) {
  return e.position().left;
}).get();
```

---

**I would appreciate if someone can explain to me which part I get wrong and provide me with the correct method.**

*(or other smart methods besides using `.map()`*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using [map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) the right way, but you're assuming the `e` argument passed to the mapping function is a jQuery object. It actually is a DOM element, and as such does not support the [position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/) method.

You can solve this problem by writing:

```
var arr = $(".matchME").map(function(i, e) {
    return $(e).position().left;
}).get();
```

Also note that, for your convenience, the current DOM element is also bound to `this`, so you can write:

```
var arr = $(".matchME").map(function() {
    return $(this).position().left;
}).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing you're missing is to wrap **e** in the JQuery selector so that it's a JQ object, and not a regular DOM object:

```
var arr = $('.match').map(function(i,e) {
    return $(e).position().left;
});
```